# Measure versus mass

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the following statement:

"There is uncountably infinite set of balls, $\mathcal{I}$, with **measure** $d\mu_{\mathcal{I}}$.
Each ball $i\in \mathcal{I}$ can be red, blu, or white. The **mass** of red balls is $n_r$. The **mass** of blue balls is $n_b$.  The **mass** of white balls is $n_w$. The total mass of balls is normalised to 1."

I'm confused on the notion of measure versus mass. Are they the same thing? What is the relation between $d\mu_{\mathcal{I}}$ and $n_r+n_b+n_w$?

Comment: Usually the term mass is used for the total variation of a signed or vector measure. But there are other possibilities. If you can give more details on where the sentence comes from maybe we can help you.

Comment: The sentence comes from a text of probability. Roughly speaking, I tend to interpret "mass of red balls" as "total number of red balls". In fact, the text proceeds by saying that the PROBABILITY of red balls is $n_r/(n_r+n_b+n_w)$

Comment: Then I don't know. Sorry. Maybe it is  more a modeling question than a mathematical one.

Comment: Mass is proportion. Normalisation to 1 allows us to speak probabilistically of it. Measure is just measure, it doesn't have to be anything specific.

Comment: Thank you. Therefore, there is no specific relation between $d\mu_I$ and $n_r, n_b, n_w$?

Comment: From this data alone, I don't see any relation. Potentially, there could be, perhaps there is additional context for this problem.